# How to find out if the name of the identifier is an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, large-files

I am exploring some programs which contain thousands of lines in them over a range of files with almost as many variables and pointers in them.
Whenever i encounter a variable, i have to trace it backwards in all the files to check whether its a simple pointer or an array, causing utter inconvenience. 
Is there a way that i make a function that tells me if there are more than one memory blocks associated with that pointer?
Or is there a built in function for that, just giving binary answer..!!!

Comment: Vim's taglist plugin is the best IMO, add the backwards regex search and it's way better...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the sizeof(a pointer pointing to an array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code may help you.

```
‎#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef char true_type;
typedef struct{ char one; char two;} false_type;

template <size_t N, typename T>
true_type test_func( T (&anarr)[N]);

false_type test_func( ... );
{
 template <typename T>
 bool is_an_array( const T& a) // const reference is important !!

 if (sizeof (test_func(a)) == sizeof(true_type) ) return true;
 else return false;
}

int main()
{ 
 char testarr[10] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'};

 if (is_an_array(testarr) ) cout << "testarr is an array" << endl; else cout <<       
 "testarr is not an array" << endl;

 char a_char = 'R';
 if (is_an_array(a_char)) cout << "a_char is an array" << endl; else cout << "a_char is
 not an array" << endl;

}
```

Comment: This code appears to be distinguishing between a char and a char array, not a char pointer and a char array. 

It will also fail to do even that with a dynamically allocated array (the OP talks about memory blocks, so presumably dynamic arrays are what he or she is interested in).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no -- it's hard to tell even at run-time whether a pointer is to an array or not.

If you use a good IDE, that will likely let you hover over a variable name and show you the deinition, which in lot of cases will give you the answer you're after.

I use Eclipse, which I find to be pretty good at telling me the types of variables. Others will use other IDES; YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a cross-referencing tool. There's a chance that its parser is dumb enough not to be hampered by errors as much as a full-fledged IDE. [Source Navigator](http://sourcenav.berlios.de/) is one with which I played a little years ago.

Comment: Oh, well. Cross referencing requires being able to recognize scopes and declarations, but not ordinary statements. Some may try and do their job with a bunch of regular expressions, others may know enough to skip over statements, without having to check their validity. Hence my (sensible! ;-) answer.